# DayNightOverlay with night lights layer possible?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i am currently running a normal maps api with javascript. Now i want to enhance it by adding the daynightoverlay from this github resource-

https://github.com/marmat/google-maps-api-addons/blob/master/daynightoverlay/src/daynightoverlay.js

Which is relatively simply. Now to this, i want to replace the dark shaded region depicting night time with the night time layer from this link -

https://earthbuilder.google.com/10446176163891957399-13737975182519107424-4/mapview/

Which is where the problem comes in. Is it possible to selectively apply the layer instead of for the whole map to depict night time ?

Comment: How about the map theme ? https://snazzymaps.com/style/30/cobalt

Comment: snazzy maps theme is for the whole map. Whereas what i am looking for is a layer of distinction between areas experiencing day and night .

Comment: Google documents has good example of adding custom overlay https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple